# How can I get the full object of currently logged ApplicationUser (EF6)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I searched a solution for this but the one I found seems not working or very old.

I have a User object that has a list, but when I try to get it with the UserManager to add things

```
var userAux = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

It returns me the properties that are lists in null.

I also assume that db.Savechanges () will not work either so if someone knows how to proceed to make the modification, I would appreciate it if you tell me how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out how to do it. I was missing a using and VS was throwing me another random error.

```
using System.Data.Entity; <<==Important

 var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
 var userAux = db.Users.Include(u => u.ListO).First(u => u.Id == userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the `HttpContextAccessor` anywhere you want, and then use the `UserManager` to get the current user.

```
internal interface IAccountRepository
{
    Task<User> GetCurrentUser();
}
internal class AccountRepository : IAccountRepository
{
    private readonly MyDbContext my_context;
    private readonly UserManager<Entities.User> user_manager;
    private readonly HttpContextAccessor http_context;
    public AccountRepository(UserManager<Entities.User> user_manager, MyDbContext my_context, HttpContextAccessor http_context)
    {
        this.user_manager = user_manager;
        this.my_context = my_context;
        this.http_context = http_context;
    }

    public async Task<User> GetCurrentUser()
    {
        var user = await user_manager.GetUserAsync(http_context.HttpContext.User);
        return ToDto(user);
    }

    #region Conversion methods
    internal static Entities.User ToEntity(User user)
    {
        if (user == null) return null;
        return new Entities.User
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            Email = user.Email,
            UserName = user.UserName,
            PictureUrl = user.PictureUrl
        };
    }
    internal static User ToDto(Entities.User user)
    {
        if (user == null) return null;
        return new User
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            Email = user.Email,
            UserName = user.UserName,
            PictureUrl = user.PictureUrl
        };
    }
    #endregion
}
```